# Minimal area ellipse containing a given circumference

Tags: calculus, optimization, conic-sections, lagrange-multiplier

> Out of all the ellipses
>
> $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$
>
> that contain the following circumference
>
> $$x^2 + y^2 = 2y$$
>
> determine the one that has the *minimal* area.

So far I've done this (in the picture), but now I'm kinda lost on using Lagrange multipliers!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective is simple:

minimize $ab$

The contraint is tricker.

By inspection we can guess

$b>2, b>a, a>1$

If the circle is inside the ellipse, the two curves do not intersect, and this system has:

$\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1\\
x^2 +y^2 = 2y$

has no real solutions.

So, we try to find solutions, apply the quadratic formula, and then set the discriminant $\le 0.$

$x^2 + \frac {a^2}{b^2}y^2 = a^2\\
x^2 +y^2 = 2y\\
(1-\frac {a^2}{b^2})y^2 - 2y + a^2 = 0\\
y = 1 \pm \sqrt{1 - a^2(1-\frac {a^2}{b^2})}$

$1 - a^2(1-\frac {a^2}{b^2})\le 0$

And, the minimal ellipse will be when the two curves are tangent.

$a^4 + b^2 - a^2b^2 = 0$

$f(a,b,\lambda) = ab + \lambda(a^4 + b^2 - a^2b^2)\\
\nabla f = 0$

$b + 4a^3\lambda + 2ab^2\lambda= 0\\
a + 2b\lambda + 2a^2b\lambda=0\\
b^2 = 2a^4$

$a^4 +2a^4 - 2a^6 = 0\\
a^4(3 -2a^2)= 0\\
a^2= \frac 32\\
b^2 = \frac {9}{2}$

$ab = \frac {3\sqrt 3}{2}$

$\pi ab = \frac {3\sqrt 3 \pi}{2}$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks, I see my where my mistake was.

Answer (score 1):

We want to minimize $f(a,b)=\pi ab$ subject to the constraint that the circle $x^2+y^2=2y$ lies inside the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.

Letting $x^2=2y-y^2$ the two figures will intersect for any $a,\,b$ satisfying

$$ \frac{2y-y^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=0 $$

The discriminant of this quadratic is

$$ 4b^4+4a^2b^2(a^2-b^2) $$

Since we wish for no intersection or at most two points of tangency we require that

$$ 4b^4+4a^2b^2(a^2-b^2) \le0$$

which simplifies to the requirement

$$ g(a,b)=b^2+a^4-a^2b^2\le0 \tag{1}$$

One may then apply

$$\nabla f(a,b)=\lambda\nabla g(a,b)$$

together with $(1)$ to obtain the result that

$$ a=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}\quad b=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

[image: Minimal ellipse]

Comment: Well, it looks like @Doug M beat me to it by 7 seconds.

Comment: Thanks anyway Sir, for both questions, really helped me out : ) @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: You are welcome.